# How to write to sqlite days of week?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I want to write to sqlite database checked day of weeks. For example, I have 7 checkBoxes, and I need to write checked items to database in one field. And when I will get this field from db, I need parse it.
 How to do this better? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it in integer type and parse with the method:

```
public int serializeDays(ArrayList<Boolean> isDayActive)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        result &= ((isDayActive.get(i) ? 1 : 0) << i);
    return result;
}
```

when you read from db deserialize with the code:

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> deserializeDays(Integer fromBase)
{
    ArrayList<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        result.add((fromBase >> i) & 1 == 1 ? true : false);
    return result;
}
```